# Procedure in Extracting JSON Array Elements

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have the following array response from a server to an android app.

```
[
{"1":
[{"name":"IEEE Meeting"},{"date":"2012-04-24 10:30:00"},{"Room":"ZACH102"},{"descr":"Final Meeting"},{"D":0.0057}]},
{"2":
[{"name":"Senior Design Demo"},{"date":"2012-04-24 16:30:00"},{"Room":"ZACH111A"},{"descr":"Demo"},{"D":0.019}]}
]
```

I perform a conversion to a JSONArray after receiving the response.

```
arr = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
```

How would I go about extracting the individual elements of name, date, room and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, its of this order
Array of objects 1, 2
  - Each object 1, 2 has an array of different objects name, date, etc.

1. Convert the whole data in to a string.
2. Create a new JSONArray(string).
3. Loop over the array. (you'll get the count using length()).
4. Get the first object by using getJSONObject().
5. Get the array in the first object using getJSONArray.
6. Now using length() again you'll get the number of JSONObjects in it.
7. Loop over the num of objects and call get JSONObject() first followed by getString() or getDouble().
8. Repeat over the list of other objects and repeat step 4 - 7.

Comment: @maknelly Hi, I just wrote a tutorial on JSON parsing in android. Since you recently had some trouble with it, I was wondering if you could go through it and see if it is helpful. Thanks!
http://www.shubhayu.com/android/json-parser-tutorial-for-android-using-jsonobjects

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the documentation for [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html)?

From the documentation, the internal form is an object having `get` and `opt` methods for accessing the values by index, and `put` methods for adding or replacing values. The values can be any of these types: `Boolean`, `JSONArray`, `JSONObject`, `Number`, `String`, or the `JSONObject.NULL` object.

A `get` method returns a value if one can be found, and throws an exception if one cannot be found. An `opt` method returns a default value instead of throwing an exception, and so is useful for obtaining optional values.

The generic `get()` and `opt()` methods return an object which you can cast or query for type. There are also typed `get` and `opt` methods that do type checking and type coercion for you.

Comment: I was wondering if I had to select the first object by getJSONObject(1) and then from the object I get name, date? In the first Object, 1 is the key for an array but then how do I extract the elements from that array?

Comment: From your server response, you have a JSONArray with two elements of type JSONObject. Every JSONOject has a name/value pair. In your case the value is another JSONArray. This JSONArray has 5 elements also of type JSONObject. Each of these correpsonds to your name, date room, and so on....

Answer (score 0):

you can get all the parameters like this

```
JSONArray main_array = json.getJSONArray("array");
for(int i=0;i<main_array.length();i++)  {               
    main_object = main_array.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = main_object.getString("name");
    String date = main_object.getString("date");
}
```